# Get Input Element Row and Col using only addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Beginners Javascript question:

1) I need to get the column and row of an input element after the user enter some data on a particular input element and hit .

I want to use addEventListener instead of add event per element in the table.

2) I need to set focus on the next record, first column after user is done with current row.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event) {
    let str =
      "KeyboardEvent: key='" + event.key + "' | code='" + event.code + "'";
    
    //Need #1. need to know row and col here 
    //something like
    alert(this.cellIndex);
    alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
    //to do stuff
    //switch(col)
    // case 0:
    //    do stuff for date here ex: instead of date,if user enter S and hit <enter>. I would put today's date on this field
    // case 1:
    //    do stuff for description here
    //Need #2. Set focus to next row set at date field for user to continue data entry
    
    let el = document.createElement("span");
    el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
 document.getElementById("output").appendChild(el);
  },
  true
);

function InsertServiceLineRow(r) {
  SrvTbl = document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl");
  var i = Number(r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex) + 2; //to account for the two header rows
  var Row = (SrvTbl.insertRow(i).innerHTML =
    '<tr><td><input type="text" size=10 name="Date"</td><td><input type="text" size=30 name="Desc"</td><td><label onclick="InsertServiceLineRow(this)">+</label><label onclick="RemoveServiceLineRow(this)">--</label></td></tr>');
  var Row = (SrvTbl.insertRow(i + 1).innerHTML =
    '<tr><td colspan=3>Notes<input type="text" size=50 name="Note"</td></tr>');
}

function RemoveServiceLineRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl").deleteRow(i);
  document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0.1px solid black;
}
th {
  color: white;
  background-color: #81C784;
}
```

```html
<table id="SrvLineTbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Add/Rem Row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Notes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" size=10 name="Date" </td>
      <td><input type="text" size=30 name="Desc" </td>
        <td size=20><label for="Add" onclick="InsertServiceLineRow(this)">+</label>
          <label for="Rem" onclick="RemoveServiceLineRow(this)">--</label>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Notes<input type="text" size=50 name="Note" </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use just use the `onkeydown` attribute on your INPUT elements e.g. `onkeydown="doSomething(this)"`? You're currently attaching the event to ALL elements, not just INPUT elements. Although Naren's code achieves what you want, it will also cause errors if the user keys down on any other element on the page.

Comment: @Mikey I understood what you meant, I am changing it to only check for keydown in the table

Comment: @NarenMurali Thank you so much. This is just what I needed.  Being a beginner, it will take me some times to understand what the new codes meant. Ironically, if I just add the **event.target.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex** and the **event.target.parentElement.cellIndex** to my existing alert statement, I also get the correct row and column. Like I said. lots or learning on my part.

Comment: @LearnMe You're welcome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the code I have made here does what you want, the last point alone is confusing, since there is no way to find out whether the user is actually done with a row, please refer the below code and let me know where it is lacking.

```js
document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl").addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event) {
    let str =
      "KeyboardEvent: key='" + event.key + "' | code='" + event.code + "'";
    
    //Need #1. need to know row and col here 
    //something like
    console.log("The row is : ", event.target.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex);
    console.log("The column is : ", event.target.parentElement.cellIndex);
    //to do stuff
    //switch(col)
    // case 0:
    //    do stuff for date here ex: instead of date,if user enter S and hit <enter>. I would put today's date on this field
    // case 1:
    //    do stuff for description here
    //Need #2. Set focus to next row set at date field for user to continue data entry
    
    let el = document.createElement("span");
    el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
 document.getElementById("output").appendChild(el);
  },
  true
);
for (var j of document.querySelectorAll("#SrvLineTbl tr > td label:nth-child(1)")){
  j.addEventListener("click", InsertServiceLineRow);
}
for (var j of document.querySelectorAll("#SrvLineTbl tr > td label:nth-child(2)")){
  j.addEventListener("click", RemoveServiceLineRow);
}
function InsertServiceLineRow(r) {
  SrvTbl = document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl");
  console.log(SrvTbl);
  var i = Number(r.target.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex) + 2; //to account for the two header rows
  var Row = (SrvTbl.insertRow(i).innerHTML =
    '<tr><td><input type="text" size=10 name="Date"</td><td><input type="text" size=30 name="Desc"</td><td><label>+</label><label>--</label></td></tr>');
  var Row = (SrvTbl.insertRow(i + 1).innerHTML =
    '<tr><td colspan=3>Notes<input type="text" size=50 name="Note"</td></tr>');
      SrvTbl.querySelector("#SrvLineTbl tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ") > td label:nth-child(1)").addEventListener("click", InsertServiceLineRow);
      SrvTbl.querySelector("#SrvLineTbl tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ") > td label:nth-child(2)").addEventListener("click", RemoveServiceLineRow);
}

function RemoveServiceLineRow(r) {
  var i = r.target.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl").deleteRow(i);
  document.getElementById("SrvLineTbl").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0.1px solid black;
}
th {
  color: white;
  background-color: #81C784;
}
```

```html
<table id="SrvLineTbl">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Add/Rem Row</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Notes</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" size=10 name="Date" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" size=30 name="Desc"> </td>
        <td size=20><label for="Add">+</label>
          <label for="Rem">--</label>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Notes<input type="text" size=50 name="Note"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="output">
</div>
```